# Is there name for arithmetic mean divided by RMS average?

Tags: statistics, terminology

Is there a mathematical term for the ratio of arithmetic mean to the root mean square average?

(FWIW, in the context where I'm concerned about this the component values will always be >= 0.)

Answer (score 3):

The nearest thing I can think of (but it is not quite there!) is the *signal to noise ratio*. The reciprocal is called the [Coefficient of Variation,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) and a few other names. The article has a link to SNR.

Comment: It's not quite the coefficient of variation, but there's an algebraic relation along the lines of $\sqrt{1-(\frac\sigma\mu)^2}$ (though the signs in that expression come out differently each time I try to derive it, so caveat lector!)

Comment: To be more accurate, the quantity that OP is interested in is equal to $1/\sqrt{\text{COV}^2+1}$, or $\cos(\arctan( \text{COV}))$

Comment: CV appears to relate mean to standard deviation, and I'm taking the ratio of mean and RMS average, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: +1 as the question immediately made me think of BEE in Navy ET school during the communications phase. *Sorry, nothing more or better to contribute.*